# Google Analytics: Which domains are sending data

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Is there a way to tell which sites my Google Analytics tracking code is implemented on? I am suspecting it may have been used with different micro landing pages with different domains and sub-domains. (Our developers were testing a cross domain tracking but did not went as expected)

I could not figure out where to see this on my GA reports, tried to search it but all ends up explaining referrals list which I am not looking for:(

[image: Advanced Filter]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question within the scope of the help center. Having said that - in your behaviour/pages report select "hostname" as secondary dimension, or create a custom report with hostnames as dimension.

Comment: Hello @EikePierstorff thank you for your comment. Should I remove the question? Sorry if I made anything wrong but I thought I could get some help from experienced GA users here.

Comment: Hi Jerry, no big deal, it's just that this site is supposed to be about programming (see the help center:https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and this seems more like a reporting issue. There are sister sites to this one (e.g. webmaster.stackechange.com) which might be more fitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check what Hostnames are sending data to the GA reports for a Property, via the *Audience > Technology > Network report*. Change the Primary Dimension from Service Provider to Hostname.

Filters are not retroactive, so you can instead create and apply a Segment based on Conditions to Filter Sessions Include based on Hostname that exactly matches yourdomain.com.
Doing this will allow you too also view the historical data in your reports in relation to valid Hostname

More info on building segments from the GA Help Center
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried to view that report but I get only one domain. There are two filters, one is only to include the domain I see. This might be the reason. The other one is an advance filter which I'll add a screen shot on my original post. Not sure what it does

Comment: In which case you will only see the data for the domain that the first filter is allowing. Was the All Web Site Data default View left filter free as per "best practices"? If so then you will be able to see what other domains may be sending traffic in the unfiltered View..

Comment: Genious! Yes there is an unfiltered one:) How did I not think on this. @Bronwyn thank you so much